# Syncfusion Javascript Tab - Change Tab button height / Font size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, syncfusion

I'm currently trying to build a site using Syncfusion Javascript controls. I've searched everywhere trying to find a way to change the height of the `Tab` control. I'm trying to change the height of the tab button itself rather than the tab body.

I've tried creating a simple CSS style that changes the font-size, but that was unsuccessful.

```
<style>
.TabOverride{
    font-size: 5px;

}
</style>
```

Here I assign the TabOverride css to the control, but it does not work. Setting the itemSize to 8px does not work either.

```
$("#TabView").ejTab({
            cssClass: "TabOverride",
            showCloseButton: true,
            enableTabScroll: true,
            showRoundedCorner: true,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            itemSize: "8px"
        });
```

Here is the support page for the Tab control.
https://help.syncfusion.com/js/tab/getting-started

I feel like this must be possible because in the WindowsForm Syncfusion tab there is a property called ItemSize for this purpose. That is why I tried itemSize in the jquery. This should be all CSS right? So it has to be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the Tab header size using headerSize property. Please refer the code snippet:

```js
$("#TabView").ejTab({
            cssClass: "TabOverride",
            showCloseButton: true,
            enableTabScroll: true,
            showRoundedCorner: true,
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            headerSize: "20px"
        });
```

```css
.TabOverride ul li a , .TabOverride ul li div{
    font-size: 5px;
     }
```

Refer the API documentation link for headerSize property: https://help.syncfusion.com/api/js/ejtab#members:headersize

JS Playground sample link: http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/gh4uq3ff

Regards,
Karthikeyan V.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I get home.

Comment: This works, however it does not reposition the close "X" so it is too low. How can I keep the close button in the center of the height?

Comment: can you help with keeping the close button in the center?

Answer (score 0):

This is my own answer just for a reminder of the other things needing to be considered with the Tab Control. Thanks to @karthik I was able to complete what I needed as well as refine it to work better.

Here is the final solution and output:

In CSS declare two separate styles as such:

```
/*The tab text*/
.TabOverride ul li a{
    font-size: 13px;
}

/*The Close 'X" on each tab*/
.TabOverride ul li div{
    margin-top: 1% !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

I separate the styles so that I can color the 'X' red.

Next I use jQuery to initiate the tab and set the `headerSize` to adjust the size of the tab button.

```
$("#TabView").ejTab({
        cssClass: "TabOverride",
        showCloseButton: true,
        enableTabScroll: true,
        showRoundedCorner: true,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        headerSize: "29px",
        beforeItemRemove: function (args) {
            if (args.index == 0) {
                args.cancel = true;
            } else {
                RemoveTab(args.index);
            }
        }
```

The final output looks like this:

[image: Tab Screenshot]

Comment: Hi Michael, Great work.
Sorry, just now i saw your comments

Comment: @karthik maybe you can help me remove the close button from the first tab.